# ActiveRecord Attachment Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, attachment

I have an attachment in an object, but when I try to save the object using an image uploaded from a view, I'm getting the following error:

```
Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 46ms
[Rollbar] Reporting exception: Failed to save the new associated logo.
[Rollbar] Exception not reported because Rollbar is disabled
ActiveRecord::RecordNotSaved (Failed to save the new associated logo.):
```

The code (When call save the error is thrown)

```
logo = Attachment::Logo.new(:asset => params[:logo])
  obj.logo = logo
  if obj.save
```

The object has the Logo

```
has_one :logo, class_name: 'Attachment::Logo', as: :attachable, :dependent => :destroy
```

Comment: You're calling both `Attachment::Logo` and `Attachment::AccountLogo` -- which is it?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I've already edit the question. It's just Attachment::Logo.

Comment: Can you add the form you are sending the params from?

If you want to upload files to Rails, you can use [Carrierwave](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave). It will make your life much easier.